# Clean Kitchen items after that find a wound in finger

Tags: taharah

Assalamu Alikum,

I have cleaned my kitchen Items and Home appliances, After that when i clean my hand i feel little pain in my finger and i noticed a small wound. It may happen during cleaning the kitchen items. I am confused as when i was cleaning the items there is a possibility that this wound may bleed and as blood is impure it make all the kitchen items impure. I didn't see blood but most probably it bleed and i didn't notice as i was cleaning with water and blood may dilute in water which i used to clean kitchen items and appliances..

What should i do now, I have to clean all items again or Just leave it. This wound in finger is very small and i didn't see blood with my eyes but it paining and their is possibility of bleeding, may be i didn't notice..

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The general ruling (according to the Hanafis) is that if there is doubt as to whether *najasah* is involved, it is to be disregarded.  "Leave that which makes you doubt for that which does not make you doubt."

In your case, you are not sure that you bled, nor are there any signs of bleeding (either in the water or on the appliances).  It is fair to assume that no bleeding was involved, and that your kitchen remains *tahir*.